# Alias of VERSION for last migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Instead of running this for migrating down the most recent version

```
$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20110713230446
```

I would like to use an alias e.g.

```
$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=previous
```

Does an alias like this exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The alias is `rake db:rollback`

Comment: Thanks, sometimes we forget about some obvious basics.